# Setting control content in a Style is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I try to create a custom spin control. It must contain 2 buttons (left & right) + text (textblock) in the middle.
So I've created 
.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="...CustomSpinControl"
 ....
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding ShiftLeftLowCommand}" Style="{Binding LeftButtonStyle, Mode=OneTime}"/>
    <TextBlock>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
      <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" />
    </TextBlock>
    <RepeatButton Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding ShiftRightLowCommand}" Style="{Binding RightButtonStyle, Mode=OneWay}"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And xaml.cs

```
namespace UserControls
{
    [StyleTypedProperty (
    Property = "LeftButtonStyle",
    StyleTargetType = typeof (RepeatButton))]
    [StyleTypedProperty (
    Property = "RightButtonStyle",
    StyleTargetType = typeof (RepeatButton))]

    public partial class CustomSpinControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
#region LowShiftValue
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LowShiftValueProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register ("LowShiftValue", typeof (int), typeof (CustomSpinControl),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (1, OnLowShiftValueChanged));

        public static void OnLowShiftValueChanged (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((CustomSpinControl)d).RaisePropertyChanged ("LowShiftValue");
        }

        public int LowShiftValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue (LowShiftValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue (LowShiftValueProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion
....
}
```

When I use the control I create a style like this

```
<Style x:Key="RightSpin2" TargetType="RepeatButton" >
      <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Border Background="Transparent" Height="20">
            <Viewbox >
              <Canvas  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56.9355" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65.8237">
                <Canvas  Height="56.936" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="-0.936" Width="65.877">
                  <Path Data="F1M55.876,0.001L0,0.003 0,56.936 55.876,56.936C61.376,56.936,65.876,52.436,65.876,46.936L65.876,10C65.876,4.5,61.376,0.001,55.876,0.001" Fill="BlueViolet" Height="56.936" Canvas.Left="0.001" Canvas.Top="0" Width="65.876"/>
                  <Path Data="F1M0,28.644C0,30.844,1.559,31.744,3.464,30.644L26.131,17.556C28.037,16.456,28.037,14.656,26.131,13.556L3.464,0.47C1.559,-0.629,0,0.27,0,2.47z" Fill="#FF999999" Height="31.113" Canvas.Left="21.128" Canvas.Top="13.147" Width="27.561"/>
                  <Path Data="F1M56.125,0L0,0 0,26.956C36.817,26.518,65.824,25.488,65.824,23.865L65.824,9.735C65.824,4.422,60.939,0,56.125,0" Height="26.956" Canvas.Left="0" Opacity="0.3" Canvas.Top="0" Width="65.824">
                    <Path.Fill>
                      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF97999C" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF97999C" Offset="0.239"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF57585B" Offset="1"/>
                      </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Path.Fill>
                  </Path>
                </Canvas>
              </Canvas>
            </Viewbox>
          </Border>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And place code

```
<UserControls:CustomSpinControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
    LeftButtonStyle="{StaticResource LeftSpin}"
    RightButtonStyle="{StaticResource RightSpin2}">
```

And everything is OK. But as soon as I place 2nd control with the same button styles... only last button is shown OK. When I use different (by name not by content) styles eg RightSpin & RightSpin2 then everything is OK again.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `Content` via a Style Setter.

That `Content` you've got there is a visual tree, and there is only one instance of it. A given control in XAML can have only one parent. When you apply the style to a second button, the `Border` is re-parented and vanishes from the previous button.

You're trying to create a new instance of the Border and its content for each button. The way to apply the "same" content to multiple controls at once is via a `ControlTemplate`. When a template is applied, a new visual tree is instantiated which is a clone of the template content.

Your Style should set the RepeatButton's `Template` property to a `ControlTemplate` which contains the same content you've got there.

It should probably be as simple as this:

```
<Style x:Key="RightSpin2" TargetType="RepeatButton" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border Background="Transparent" Height="20">
                    <Viewbox >
                        <Canvas  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56.9355" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65.8237">
                            <Canvas  Height="56.936" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="-0.936" Width="65.877">
                                <Path Data="F1M55.876,0.001L0,0.003 0,56.936 55.876,56.936C61.376,56.936,65.876,52.436,65.876,46.936L65.876,10C65.876,4.5,61.376,0.001,55.876,0.001" Fill="BlueViolet" Height="56.936" Canvas.Left="0.001" Canvas.Top="0" Width="65.876"/>
                                <Path Data="F1M0,28.644C0,30.844,1.559,31.744,3.464,30.644L26.131,17.556C28.037,16.456,28.037,14.656,26.131,13.556L3.464,0.47C1.559,-0.629,0,0.27,0,2.47z" Fill="#FF999999" Height="31.113" Canvas.Left="21.128" Canvas.Top="13.147" Width="27.561"/>
                                <Path Data="F1M56.125,0L0,0 0,26.956C36.817,26.518,65.824,25.488,65.824,23.865L65.824,9.735C65.824,4.422,60.939,0,56.125,0" Height="26.956" Canvas.Left="0" Opacity="0.3" Canvas.Top="0" Width="65.824">
                                    <Path.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF97999C" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF97999C" Offset="0.239"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF57585B" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Path.Fill>
                                </Path>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```